# What is the difference between window, window.top and window.parent?

Tags: javascript, html

I just noticed that `top`, `window` and `parent` variables are giving me the same value. I was testing this at gmail inbox page. Does anybody know what is the difference between these three values?

Comment: there is also a window.self which refers to the same window :)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

If you are within a frame:

- `window` refers to the current frame.
- `parent` refers to the parent of the current frame.
- `top` refers to the outermost frame.

If you're not within any frame, these will all just be a [reference to the current window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent).  If you're only within one level of frame, `parent` and `top` will both be a reference to the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is any particular browser special condition? For example in XXX top not apply...

Comment: No there shouldn't be although if your page was opened in a frame by a page from another security context (according to same origin policy, ie a different hostname) then you won't be able to access the properties inside the parent object. This is just normal security of all browsers. It prevents cross site scripting by opening another site in a frame (or being opened by another site in a frame).

Comment: In addition `self` also refers to the same object if there is not nesting.

Comment: Just a heads up, I came from "https://www.window.top/" (link)