# on click webpage open window.open() and that include frameset but window.close not working in frameset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am facing one big problem ( atleast for me )

on click webpage  i open window.open() and that include one page and that page contain iframe but window.close not working in iframe.

this is the onclick where i want to open window.open

```
 <a onclick="window.open('http://localhost:8080/xyz.jsp', 'tool','width=720,height=500,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');return false;" target="tool" href="#" class="nav5b">new style</a>
```

This is the url in  window.open in localhost:8080/xyz.jsp

this is the frame is coming

```
  <frameset>
        <iframe id=someid" width="700" src="http://localhost:8080/test.form" name="frame1" scrolling="yes">
    </frameset>
```

Comment: You can not “close” an (i)frame …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried

```
parent.window.close();
```

Comment: Glad to help. One gets so tied up with the big picture that small things escape your notice.

Answer (score 1):

"`top`" is even better , in case you have more then 2 levels of iframes "depth". Here is good link: [What is the difference between window, window.top and window.parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473946/difference-between-window-top-parent)