# Root Div Element Type Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to find the root div element and this is how i am doing it.

```
   var parentDoc = window;
    while (parentDoc !== parentDoc.parent) {
        parentDoc = parentDoc.parent;
    }
    parentDoc = parentDoc.document;
    var divContent = parentDoc.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
```

It works fine but when i resize my browser screen too small then i get an error .

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of null
```

How can i fix this? or is there any better way to do what i am doing right now using jquery or javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to do, but with jQuery you can try using the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function:

```
 var $content = $(<selector>).closest('.content');
 var content  = $content[0];
```

From jQuery site:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

You can avoid the error you described by checking nullity of `parentDoc.parent` var:

```
while (parentDoc !== parentDoc.parent) {
    if (parentDoc.parent == null) {
        break;
    }
    parentDoc = parentDoc.parent;
}
```

Comment: i am trying to get the root div then finding the child div

Comment: @user3754674: I don't think you are finding the root div at all. What you are trying to reference is the root document/frame, rather  than a `<div></div>` (otherwise I've misunderstood your question and the code you posted makes no sense at all).

Comment: root div of what? your document? some container tag? Take a closer look at the jQuery's closest function. It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is `window.top`, which has a reference to the top-most window in the hierarchy. You can find more information on it [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.top) Additionally, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473946/what-is-the-difference-between-window-window-top-and-window-parent) might help clear up some confusion regarding the differences between this and `window.parent`.

Comment: i am trying to get the root div then finding the child div