# Refresh NetSuite portlet on save/submit

Tags: javascript, portlet, netsuite

I have created a PortLet to create task in NetSuite. And new task getting create when an user press Submit button, but  portlet not geting refresh automatially. Every time user need to refreash portlet manully. Is there any way to refresh portlet on submit?

```
function formCreateTaskPL(portlet, column) {
var user = 257;
var entityid = 1985;
var trandate = nlapiDateToString(new Date());
var contact = 201;

portlet.setTitle('Quick Add Task');

var fld = portlet.addField('custpage_cust', 'text', 'Customet');
fld.setDefaultValue(entityid);

var fld = portlet.addField('custpage_user', 'text', 'User');
fld.setDefaultValue(user);  

var fld = portlet.addField('custpage_date', 'date', 'Date');
fld.setDefaultValue(trandate);

var fld = portlet.addField('custpage_contact','text','Contact');   
fld.setDefaultValue(contact);

var fld = portlet.addField('custpage_title', 'text', 'Title');
var fld = portlet.addField('custpage_text', 'longtext', 'Detail');

var url = nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET', 'customscript_create_task','customdeploy_create_task');

portlet.setSubmitButton(url, 'Submit');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-portlet-refreshe/odpaehonnmgmjkneccjjhgaoannpnghg

If you install this plugin ,Refreshes the portlets in your Netsuite Dashboard Automatically every time you login or access your netsuite Home Page.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Suitelet returning? You might try changing the setSubmitButton target parameter to _parent and have the Suitelet redirect the page.

Comment: Suitelet only create Task with the data send from Portlet and suite let not returning anything. I tried to redirect with same customer record, but when its redirected customer record opening within portlet area.

Comment: Seems you need to target the top window element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473946/what-is-the-difference-between-window-window-top-and-window-parent

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Chrome extension for this purpose. You can set your own refresh interval. Unlike the other extension linked here, it doesn't refresh browser at all, just the portlets.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/freshportlet-for-netsuite/djphbeeppdbbljolikpmhcjbodaakanh